# How to implement imbinarize in OpenCV

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, ocr, threshold

I developed script in Matlab which is analysing engraved text on a colour steal. I'm using range of morphological techniques to extract the text and read it with OCR. I need to implement it on Raspberry Pi therefore I decided to transfer my Matlab code into OpenCV (in python). I tried to transfer some methods and they work similarly but how do I implement imreconstruct and imbinarize (shown below) to OpenCV? (the challenge here is appropriate differentiate foreground and background).

Maybe I should try adding `grabCut` or `getStructuringElement` or `morphologyEx` or `dilate`? I tried them in range of combinations but have not found a perfect solution.

I will put the whole script for both if anyone could give me suggestions on how to generally improve this extraction and accuracy of OCR process I would greatly appreciate it.

> Based on bin values of grey-scale image. I change some parameters in
>   those functions:
>
> Matlab:

```
se = strel('disk', 300);
img = imtophat(img, se);
maker = imerode(img, strel('line',100,0)); %for whiter ones
maker = imerode(img, strel('line',85,0)); %for medium
maker = imerode(img, strel('line',5,0));

imgClear = imreconstruct(maker, img);

imgBlur = imgaussfilt(imgClear,1); %less blur for whiter frames

BW = imbinarize(imgBlur,'adaptive','ForegroundPolarity','Bright',...
    'Sensitivity',0.7);   %process for medium

BW = imbinarize(imgBlur, 'adaptive', 'ForegroundPolarity',...
        'Dark', 'Sensitivity', 0.4); % process for black and white

res = ocr(BW, 'CharacterSet', '0123456789', 'TextLayout', 'Block');
res.Text;
```

> OpenCv

```
kernel = numpy.ones((5,5),numpy.uint8)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
erosion = cv2.erode(blur,kernel,iterations = 1)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

#bremove = cv2.grabCut(opening,mask,rect,bgdModelmode==GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
#th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(opening,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,11,2)

ret, thresh= cv2.threshold(opening,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image2.png'),config='stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

Here is the input image:

[image]

[image: Matlab outcome (result 573702)]

[image: OpenCV outcome (result 573102]

[image: Light colour image]

[image: Matlab process full detection rate]

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised at how much difference between matlab and opencv there is when they both appear to use the same algorithm. Why do you run `imbinarize` twice? What does the sensitivity keyword actually do (mathematically, behind the background). Because they obviously have several steps more than just the bare OTSU.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show(img):
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()

img = cv2.imread("letters.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3), 0)
erosion = cv2.erode(blur, kernel, iterations=3)
opening = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel)

th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(opening, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 45, 2)
show(th3)

kernel2 = cv2.getGaussianKernel(6, 2) #np.ones((6,6))
kernel2 = np.outer(kernel2, kernel2)
th3 = cv2.dilate(th3, kernel2)
th3 = cv2.erode(th3, kernel)
show(th3)
```

The images that get displayed are:

[image: First image, the immediate result of thresholding]

After a bit of cleaning up:

[image: A bit more cleaned up and lean. Not really as nice as matlab output.]

So all in all not the same and certainly not as nice as matlab. But the basic principle seems the same, it's just that the numbers need playing with.

A better approach would probably be to do a threshold by the mean of the image and then use the output of that as a mask to adaptive threshold the original image. Hopefully then the results would be better than both opencv and matlab.

Try doing it with ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C you can get some really nice results but there's more trash lying around. Again, maybe if you can use it as a mask to isolate the text and then do tresholding again it might turn out to be better. Also the shape of the erosion and dilation kernels will make a big difference here.

Comment: I'm a beginner on OpenCV. Appreciate for any comment on my answer given below.

Comment: I run `imbinarize` twice for different shades of images, one for darker one for lighter, this is just a code taken from context, I have decision making process in between depending on mean grayscale value. That's the point I do not know what does `sensitivity` do, can't find equation for it. I tried with different methods of adaptive threshold but as you said it leaves more trash which OCR does not like at it gives false positives. How do you change the shape of erosion as I have `square` or `line` as I have in MatLab.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the code to have a positive result based on your engraved text sample.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def show(img):
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()

# load the input image
img = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/engraved_text.jpg',0);
show(img)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img, 60, 120, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # turn 60, 120 for the best OCR results
kernel = np.ones((5,3),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)
show(mask)

# I used a version of OpenCV with Tesseract, you may use your pytesseract and set the modes as:
#   OCR Enginer Mode (OEM) = 3 (defualt = 3)
#   Page Segmentation mode (PSmode) = 11 (defualt = 3)
tesser = cv2.text.OCRTesseract_create('C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tessdata/','eng','0123456789',11,3)
retval = tesser.run(mask, 0) # return string type

print 'OCR:' + retval
```

Processed image and OCR output:

[image]

It would be great if you can feedback your test results with more sample images.

[opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv)[python](/questions/tagged/python)[tesseract](/questions/tagged/tesseract)[ocr](/questions/tagged/ocr)

Comment: Yeah this pointed me to right direction, I can take more control of my binarization process however I'm still missing something when it comes to lighter images. I somehow need to remove the reflection from the image which in MatLab is achieved through `imreconstruct`

Comment: I will continue experimenting with your implementation and add others people suggestions.

Comment: This threshold works nicely on dark images but not as good on slightly lighter images. The value of threshold always have big difference on the image. Mean value of the sample I provided here is 110 but when I give 139 I need to decrease thresh to 40 which is not good as I would have massive amount of if statements and have to adapt thresh for each value. I need something more intelligent. In Matlab I have 3 `binarization` techniques for all 255 values.

Comment: @UZIERSKI check my new post on the lighter.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from your code is you have used tophat filtering in your Matlab code as the first step. However, I couldn't see the same in your python OpenCV code.
Python has built in tophat filter try applying that for getting similar result

`kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
 tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)`

Also, try using CLAHE it gives better contrast to your image and then apply blackhat to filter out small details.

`clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
 cl1 = clahe.apply(img)`

I have got better results by applying these transformations.

Comment: I did notice that as well and now I added `TOPHAT` to my code, thank you. For `clahe` I receive an error: `error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/clahe.cpp:260: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function apply`

Answer (score 0):

Tried below, it works to recognize the lighter engraved text sample. Hope it helps.

```
def show(img):
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()

# load the input image
img = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/engraved_text2.jpg',0);
show(img)

# apply CLAHE to adjust the contrast
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5.1, tileGridSize=(5,3))
cl1 = clahe.apply(img)
img = cl1.copy()
show(img)

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3), 1)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img, 125, 150, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # turn 125, 150 for the best OCR results

kernel = np.ones((5,3),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)
show(mask)

# I used a version of OpenCV with Tesseract, you may use your pytesseract and set the modes as:
#   Page Segmentation mode (PSmode) = 11 (defualt = 3)
#   OCR Enginer Mode (OEM) = 3 (defualt = 3)
tesser = cv2.text.OCRTesseract_create('C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tessdata/','eng','0123456789',11,3)
retval = tesser.run(mask, 0) # return string type

print 'OCR:' + retval
```

[image]